# Recursive function to calculate the height of a BST

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree, nodes

The BST is as follows:

```
    50 (Root 1)
   / \
  40  80 (Root 2)
 / \
20 41
```

As you can see there are 2 root's that I am dealing with. I have tried the following code which does return the height of the tree from ROOT 1. I don't quite exactly know how to return the height from ROOT 2.

Any help on how to solve would be appreciated.

```
// Java program to find height of tree 

// A binary tree node 
class Node  
{ 
    int data; 
    Node left, right; 

    Node(int item)  
    { 
        data = item; 
        left = right = null; 
    } 
} 

class BinaryTree  
{ 
    Node root; 

    int maxDepth(Node node)  
    { 
        if (node == null) 
            return 0; 
        else 
        { 
            /* compute the depth of each subtree */
            int lDepth = maxDepth(node.left); 
            int rDepth = maxDepth(node.right); 

            /* use the larger one */
            if (lDepth > rDepth) 
                return (lDepth + 1); 
             else 
                return (rDepth + 1); 
        } 
    } 

    /* Driver program to test above functions */
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    { 
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree(); 

        tree.root = new Node(1); 
        tree.root.left = new Node(2); 
        tree.root.right = new Node(3); 
        tree.root.left.left = new Node(4); 
        tree.root.left.right = new Node(5); 

        System.out.println("Height of tree is : " +  
                                      tree.maxDepth(tree.root)); 
    }
```

Comment: When you consider Root2 as root, is Root1 then considered its child? Or is Root2 regarded as the root of the subtree (which is empty in the example)?

Comment: why don't you just try to pass the value of tree.root.right from the main call to maxDepth() function

Comment: I don't quite get your question. You want to calculate the height of tree, starting from ROOT 2? How would you input that you want to start from ROOT 2 in the provided example? The way I see it currently, you'd have to:
1 - Find ROOT 2 and return the NODE
2 - Apply maxDepth on that returned NODE

Comment: Please define the phrase "the height from ROOT 2", or at least tell us what it would be in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function for finding max depth seems like to work correctly. So fixing this issue is pretty simple.

```
System.out.println("Height of tree is : " +  
                                  tree.maxDepth(tree.root));
```

The above line prints out the height of the tree starting at the root. But if you were to start at "root 2" as you call it you would need to modify this line to start at the correct node.

```
System.out.println("Height of tree is : " +  
                                  tree.maxDepth(tree.root.right));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an item to a Tree class should be made through a insert method.
And we can make the Node class private, it is used only by BinaryTree class.

A better data structure for a tree should be like the following, which has public insert and height methods.

```
public class BinaryTree {

    private class Node {

        private int value;
        private Node left;
        private Node right;

        private Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private Node root;

    public void insert(int item) {

        var node = new Node(item);
        if (root == null) {
            root = node;
            return;
        }

        var current = root;

        while (true) {

            if (item < current.value) {
                if (current.left == null) {
                    current.left = node;
                    break;
                }
                current = current.left;

            } else {
                if (current.right == null) {
                    current.right = node;
                    break;
                }
                current = current.right;
            }
        }
    }

    public int height() {
       return height(root);
    }

    private int height(Node root) {
        if (root == null)
            return -1;

        if (isLeaf(root))
            return 0;

        return 1 + Math.max(height(root.left), height(root.right));
    }

    private boolean isLeaf(Node node) {
        return node.left == null && node.right == null;
    }
}
```

And to use it, just add some values, and print the height.
It is way easier to insert an item with this tree class.

```
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();

        tree.insert(50);
        tree.insert(40);
        tree.insert(80);
        tree.insert(20);
        tree.insert(41);

        System.out.println(tree.height());
```